# Output is showing multiple string values with integer

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    int input {};
    cout << "Input number: ";
    cin >> input;

    for (int i {1}; i <= input; i++) {
        cout << "The natural numbers are: " << i;


    }
}
```

I am trying to show the natural numbers of an integer being input and I set up the loop and everything but when my result prints out it prints multiple lines of the string instead of the result I want which is for example if i entered 5 (The natural numbers are: 1 2 3) instead its saying
The natural numbers are: 1 
the natural numbers are: 2
the natural numbers are: 3

Comment: Well, yes, this is because this is exactly what you told your computer to do: execute a loop, counting from 1 to the given number, and each time through the loop print "The natural numbers are: <n>", where "<n>" is the number being counted. And that's exactly what you see. If you don't want to see "The natural numbers are: " before each number, then just change your program accordingly.

Comment: perhaps you wanted to write `endl` instead of `i` at the end of your sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Print once  `"The natural numbers are: "` at the beginning of the loop as you don't want to repeat it.

```c
cout << "The natural numbers are: ";
for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
   cout << i << ' ';
    }
```

Comment: @naustin288, "We don't do that here" :D wakanda forever!